# When I am converting Date into months and plotting a boxplot the data against month why does it gets aligned alphabetically

Tags: r, time-series, boxplot

I have a time series data of daily cases against time. I have grouped the data against month and changed the month variable using `months` function into January, February, etc. Now when I plot the box plot of the daily cases against the month variable, the plot gets aligned alphabetically instead chronologically.

[image: Box Plot]

Here is the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1keyeQrLQj_IAFfuvUYKa7pPgVNGbn-_N/view?usp=sharing)
used to plot.

The following code I used.

```
y<-read.csv('COVID.csv',row.names=1)
y$Date<-as.Date(row.names(y),'%d-%m-%Y')
row.names(y)<-NULL
y<-y%>%group_by(month=floor_date(Date,unit='month'))
y$month<-months(y$month)
boxplot(y$Daily.Cases~y$month)
```

Here is the [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GsQlX3z8NJOji0UZcd_yzZio2vFD_apeO3RsE0aTLY/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried the solution and it gave the following [image: graph]

As you can see, I don't have any data for the month of November and December but it's showing up in the graph.

Comment: Make `month` an ordered factor, i.e. `y$month <- factor(y$month, levels = month.name)`

Comment: I tried it and it's working but it is also giving me the months for which there's no data available.

Comment: After setting the order you can drop unused levels with `y$month <- droplevels(y$month)`.